# AngularJS ui-router state won't follow route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

What's wrong with this syntax?

if I click this link: **#/app/games/game/{{id}}/team**
it redirects to: **#/app/games** instead of going to the above

gameitem.html template:

```
<a class="tab-item" ng-href="#/app/games/game/{{id}}/team">Team</a>
```

which renders to: **#/app/games/game/2/team**

the routing state:

```js
.state('app.game', {
  url: "/games/game/:id",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/gameitem.html",
      controller: 'GameItemController'
    }
  }
})
.state('app.game.team', {
  url: "/games/game/:id/team",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/gameitem-team.html",
      controller: 'GameItemTeamController'
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ng-href with ui-router. Instead use ui-sref.

```
ui-sref="app.game.team({id:id})"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ui-sref, as mentioned in previous answers. But couse of your problem is erroneously defined url in sub state.

'app.game' is parent state, 'app.game.team' substate - because dot notation (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#dot-notation).
In nested states are url concatenated. Correct url of 'app.game.team' state should be "/team" only (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ui-sref`, that way you directly point to your state, so you can afterwards change the URL and it will handle that for you templatewise:

```
<a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.game.team({'id': id})">Team</a>
```

Reference:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

And pointed out by Martin in the comments, the URL property in a childstate, appends the used value to the parent's URL. Prepending it with `^` makes it an absolute route.

Reference:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states

Comment: using ui-sref is turning the url into:
`#/app/games/game/2/games/game/2/team`

and if I use:
`<a class="tab-item" ui-sref="#/app/games/game/{{id}}/team>`

I get an Error:
`Error: Could not resolve '#/app/games/game/2/team' from state 'app.game'`

Comment: It is not breaking your URL, you have your URL defined wrong in your config. You either need to prepend it with ^ or change it to '/team'. By default states inherit the urls of there parent states.

Comment: Thank Martin, that did it indeed. Also changing the state to `app.gameteam` also fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Martin, overlooked that. I've added your comment to the answer and the reference to URL routing for nested states to make it complete.